# How to fill the blank , python re

Tags: python-3.x

What I could fill between ''' ''', then I can get the result like the picture?

```
import re
import pandas as pd
text=''' Need to fill'''
pattern="(.{1,})"
d=re.findall(pattern,text)
pd.DataFrame({"1":d[1].replace(';',',').split(','),"2":d[0].split(';')})
```

[image]

Comment: I'm unclear what you're asking. `.{1,}` is a strange way to write `.+`, but this matches any character. This regex matches any nonempty string and doesn't seem like it'll help you achieve much of anything. What's the point of this exercise, exactly?

Comment: Hi, the teacher just let us complete the contents of the text, I have no idea how to do it